# Windows Server 2008 as development machine - step by step

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2005, iis, iis-7, windows-server-2008

I have found many tutorials about using Windows Server 2003 as a development machine, and very little information about Windows Server 2008 for the same purpose.

For a nicer experience, I have followed the steps from [Convert your Windows Server 2008 to a Workstation](http://www.win2008workstation.com/wordpress/).

I am searching for the requirements and installation order for IIS 7 with IIS 6 compatibility mode, .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 (does it require the installation of `.NET Framework 3.0` feature, or can be installed directly), SQL Server 2005 SP2 (with Reporting services and Analysis Services), Visual Studio 2008 SP1.

Comment: A note about enabling the wireless service may not be a bad idea.

Comment: It's on the web site mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**`SQL Server 2005 - installation order`** (thank you Anthony)

- IIS 7 with IIS 6 backwards compatibility (for reporting services)
- KB 950636
- SQL Server 2005
- [SQL Server 2005 SP3](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=ae7387c3-348c-4faa-8ae5-949fdfbe59c4&displaylang=en)
- [Visual Studio 2005 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=BB4A75AB-E2D4-4C96-B39D-37BAF6B5B1DC&displaylang=en) (for BIDS)
- [Visual Studio 2005 SP1 update for Vista](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=90e2942d-3ad1-4873-a2ee-4acc0aace5b6&displaylang=en) (for BIDS)

**`SQL Server 2005 - links`**

- [Error message when you install SQL Server 2005 SP3 on Windows Vista: "Visual Studio 2005 has a known compatibility issue with this version of Windows"](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=960320)
- [Update for Windows Server 2008 (KB950636)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=FB0EE17E-96EB-4CBB-AC09-95A4DCF73077&displaylang=en) - Install this update to resolve an issue where SQL Server 2005 installation is not completed successfully on a system running Windows Server 2008.
- [You receive a warning message on the System Configuration Check page of the SQL Server 2005 Setup program on a computer that is running Windows Vista or a Server Core installation of Windows Server 2008](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/920201/en-us)
- [How to install and how to configure SQL Server 2005 Reporting Services on a computer that is running Windows Server 2008](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/938245/)
- [SQL Server 2005 on Windows Server 2008](http://www.codersbarn.com/post/2008/08/09/SQL-Server-2005-on-Windows-Server-2008.aspx)
- [Installing SQL Server 2005 Reporting Service on IIS 7](http://igregor.net/post/2008/01/Installing-SQL-Server-2005-Reporting-Service-on-IIS-7.aspx)
- [SQL Server User Provisioning Tool for Vista](http://blogs.msdn.com/knom/archive/2007/03/02/sql-server-user-provisioning-tool-for-vista.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

**.NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1 - installation order**

- System Update Readiness Tool
- .NET Framework 3.0 (Windows Server 2008 feature)
- [.NET Framework 3.5 SP1 (full package)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=d0e5dea7-ac26-4ad7-b68c-fe5076bba986)
- [An update for the .NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1 is available (KB959209)](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=959209)

**.NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1 - links**

- Before you install .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 on Windows Vista or Windows 2008 Server, make sure that Windows Update service is turned on.
- [Description of the System Update Readiness Tool for Windows Vista and for Windows Server 2008](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947821) - Since the .NET Framework 2.0 and 3.0 are OS components on Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008, they rely on the OS component store to be in a good state to be able to install correctly (quoted from [here](http://forums.asp.net/p/1305769/2562990.aspx))
- [**Unified .NET Framework Troubleshooting Guide**](http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/articles/454956.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

http://www.codersbarn.com/post/2008/08/09/SQL-Server-2005-on-Windows-Server-2008.aspx

I use W2K8 on VMWare Workstation for SharePoint development and it has been hassle-free from day one. Install all the IIS7 features (includes the IIS6 compatibility stuff) and you should be good to go.

Anthony :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Visual Studio 2008 - links**

- [Using Visual Studio 2008 with IIS 7.0](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/387/using-visual-studio-2008-with-iis-70/)
- [Unable to start debugging on the web server with VS2008 SP1 and IIS7](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/dc3757fc-0933-4dc7-8587-242c4ef268fe/)
- [Unable to start debugging on the web server. IIS does not list an application that matches the launched URL.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/04532b6d-e281-4b7f-a623-543dcb683e2f/)

Answer (score 1):

**IIS 7 - installation order**

- IIS 7 (Windows Server 2008 role)
- [You may be unable to manage IIS by using Server Manager if two threads access IIS at the same time](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946517/en-us)

**IIS 7 - links**

- [Installing IIS 7.0 on Windows Server 2008](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/29/installing-iis7-on-windows-server-2008/)

**IIS 7 with IIS 6 backwards compatibility - links**

- [Installing SQL Server 2005 Reporting Service on IIS 7](http://igregor.net/post/2008/01/Installing-SQL-Server-2005-Reporting-Service-on-IIS-7.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

**MSI 4.5 - installation order**

- [MSI 4.5 hotfix - Error message when you use Windows Installer (MSI) 4.5 to install multiple MSI packages in Windows Server 2008, Windows Vista, Windows Server 2003 or Windows XP: API call rejected - No actions in Context](http://support.microsoft.com/Default.aspx?kbid=958655)

**MSI 4.5 - links**

- [Update to MSI 4.5 (KB958655)](http://blogs.msdn.com/windows_installer_team/archive/2008/12/05/update-to-msi-4-5-kb958655.aspx)