# Error when installing .NET 3.5 framework over Windows Server 2008

Tags: .net, installation, windows-server-2008

I am trying to install the .NET framework over [Windows Server 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2008) build 6001 (if it helps?). I am able to install .NET 3.5, but when trying to install service pack 1 (from the following [link](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=ab99342f-5d1a-413d-8319-81da479ab0d7&displaylang=en)) I get the following error.

> Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 has encountered a problem during setup. 
>      Setup did not complete correctly. windows server 2008

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327448/windows-server-2008-as-development-machine-step-by-step/327449#327449

Answer (score 0):

We've had problems with this before. Some thoughts:

- Run the setup as an administrator; on one occasion (isolated?) it only worked as the local "administrator" account; it failed even for a domain administrator.
- Shut down [IIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services), [COM+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model#COM.2B_and_DCOM), etc. first.

Other than that; you'll want to look at the [MSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) log file.